# Find the value of $c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the roots of the equation $x^4-12x^3+cx^2+dx+81=0$ are positive then find the value of $c$.

How I find the value of $c$ ?

Comment: [Same method as here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305689/solving-equation-through-inequalities)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw $81=3^4$ and $12=3 \cdot 4$ it made me think of $(x-3)^4=x^4-12x^3+54x^2-108x+81$  That certainly has all roots positive, so if the question has a unique answer it must be $54$.  Do you trust the problem setter to have asked a question with a unique answer?  If so, this is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Sum of roots is $12$ and product is $81$ as all are positive by AM-GM $\frac {\sum a}{4}\geq (\pi a)^{\frac {1}{4}} $ and putting in value we see that AM=GM thus all roots are equal. Thus the expression is $(x-3)^4$

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305689/solving-equation-through-inequalities).

Try using AM-GM on the roots with the coefficients you already have and see what you get.